# Using Capybara's `within` scoping helper in Rails View Specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Like many, I use Capybara not only to test feature specs but also the rendered HTML in my Rails View specs.

I wrap the rendered HTML into a Capybara node -

```
require "spec_helper"

RSpec.describe "foo/show.html.erb", type: :view do
  it "should display foo" do
    render

    within(".some-class") do
      expect(page).to have_content("woohoo")
    end
  end

  def page
    @page ||= Capybara::Node::Simple.new(rendered)
  end
end
```

However, I recently noticed several tests (of similar format to the above) passing when they should actually be failing (false positive).

I tracked it down to the behavior of the `within do ... end` block - it never executes those block in my view specs. I confirmed by trying to pause execution with `binding.pry` inside the `within` block, but it never triggered. And since it never executes, all specs have been happily passing

It looks like `within` is a [Capybara Session method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FSession%3Awithin), and it makes sense that it wouldn't be intended to work with view specs as there is no "session".

1. I'm curious why the call to `within` just silently fails? What `within` method is it calling, and why doesn't it throw an error if one is not found?
2. Is there a way to make it work here with view specs? With complex rendered HTML it's incredibly convenient to have your tests scoped to a particular HTML node, which is the whole point of `within`, so I'd love to be able to use it

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default only Capybara::RSpecMatchers should be included into view specs - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec.rb#L10 -, not Capybara::DSL, so Capybaras `within` shouldn't be available (try using byebug and stepping into the within call to see what library is providing it).  You can scope your tests by using the fact that matchers/finders can be called on nodes and that scopes to the used node - so something like

```
page = Capybara.string(rendered)
scoped_node = page.find(".some-class")
expect(scoped_node).to have_content("woohoo")
expect(scoped_node.find('.contained-class')).to have_content("abcdefg")
```

Update:  After taking a quick look, the `within` you're actually calling is probably the RSpec be_within matcher which for some reason is aliased as `within` - https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/3-5-maintenance/lib/rspec/matchers.rb#L416 - not sure why since I can't think of how that would ever read well in an expectation - and basically all your statement is doing is creating a matcher that is never called and just ignoring the block passed to it.

Comment: Thanks Tom! That makes sense now, and would directly explain that behavior. Just for my own curiosity, what's the reason for not including `Capybara::DSL` in view specs? Does that library drive an actual web browser and therefore not applicable to view specs, that just render plain HTML? Shame because `within ()` is such a useful helper that reads so well!

Comment: @user2490003 Correct - Capybara::DSL consists of the session methods which drive the browser, which doesn't make sense in view specs.  You should be able to write your own `within` method for your view specs if wanted that just pushes the result of `find` (with the passed args) on the current `page` onto a stack and then define `page` to be the top of the stack or `Capybara.string(rendered)` if no page is currently defined

Comment: Perfect, even better idea. Thanks again.